# Как обновить/переоткрыть Fragment по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

я новичок в Java разработке и у меня возник вопрос, как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку в Fragment он перезапустился без анимации, грубо говоря просто обновился или пересоздался/переоткрылся так, что бы пользователь этого не заметил?

Comment: Возможно, вы пытаетесь решить неозвученную задачу неверным способом. Для чего вам обновлять фрагмент таким способом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру можно перезайти на него:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, SomeFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

и таким образом вы сможете обновить его контент. Анимация как вы понимаете будет отсутствовать.

Comment: А что нужно подставить заместо SomeFragment? при подставлении того же фрагмента в котором я и написал этот код выдает ошибку. newInstance стал красным 
```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Peremennaya.forBeginner =1;

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, GalleryFragment.newInstance()).commit();


            }
        });
```

Comment: это ваш фрагмент, который вы пытаетесь пересоздать

Comment: а .replace(R.id.container) здесь что нужно вписать? просто при нажатии на кнопку программа вылетает

Comment: я не вижу ваш код если что, я не знаю id контейнера, поэтому написал приблизительно, вам нужно использовать свои идентификаторы

Comment: а чем является контейнер? Я просто новичок и не совсем понимаю что за контейнер. Как его найти?

Comment: вы где-то должны отображать ваши фрагменты, как вариант использовать контейнера, он расположен в xml чаще всего, вот отсюда можно начать изучение например - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php

Comment: Спасибо большое! очень сильно помогли))